# Force Calculation to Round Up in C#

Tags: c#, rounding

I have this following code:

```
double calc = 21 / 6;
model.Count = Math.Round(calc, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Calc is clearly 3.5 but when I open the page it always produces 3.
How can I force the code to count any . decimal (i.e 3.1 to 3.9 is always 4)?

Comment: You can use Math.Ceiling to round up https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @MarshallTigerus I've tried Math.Ceiling but its not working with the above code?

Comment: You're dividing `int`s which will only output another `int`. So 21/6 is 3. You need to do `21D/6` or `21.0/6` instead.

Comment: @DavidG Thats the issue. Thanks!!